# Installed the wrong package

Tags: node.js, linux, reactjs, package, yarnpkg

I was installing some packages in Linux Ubuntu to begin code some projects in Node.js and react, but I did not follow the instructions on yarn's website, passed on shell only the command line `sudo apt-get install yarn`. Now, I got a wrong version installed and I can't install the right version. I also can't uninstall this wrong package. I tried everything I could think. Somebody who passed by it and got resolve it could help me?

Comment: What do you need exactly ? install yarn or change the version ?

Comment: paste the error message here, also please

Comment: along with os details - ubuntu version, node version

Comment: When check the version yarn, the answer is 0.32+git, the right version is 1.17.3. I trynig fix it and install the right version.  When i try remove the package or purge, the answer is Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Note, a seleccionar 'cmdtest' em vez de 'yarn'
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 70 não atualizados.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get remove yarn && sudo apt-get purge yarn`

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if your required version is installed or not by running this command in your terminal:

`yarn --version`

Now if the version is not installed you can run this command to remove and to install new version of it.

`sudo apt-get remove yarn && sudo apt-get purge yarn`

Answer (score -1):

The root cause of your problem is using sudo to install node/yarn. Use the NVM package to install a node/yarn under your home folder. NVM is a convenient way to work with multiple versions of node and will help you with your yarn issue.

You can use nvm - install that and you can then use any versions of node. In fact you can install more than one version of node.

First download the NVM installation script using CURL as follows

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

After downloading this script, run the script using bash as given below

```
$ bash install_nvm.sh
```

Check the installed NVM version as given below

```
$ nvm --version
```

Install any particular node version using following nvm command:

```
$ nvm install 10.19 # will install node 10.19.0
```

To use particular node version use

```
$ nvm use 10.15 # it will use node 10.15.0
```

To list out all versions of node available to you

```
   $ nvm ls
```

Finally after choosing the right version of node preferred by you, you can install yarn.

```
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

Test that Yarn is installed by running the below command -

```
yarn --version
```

With this method, you can avoid sudo issues.

If Yarn is not found in your PATH, follow these steps to add it and allow it to be run from anywhere.

Note: your profile may be in your .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, etc.

Add this to your profile: export PATH="$PATH:/opt/yarn-[version]/bin" (the path may vary depending on where you extracted Yarn to)
In the terminal, log in and log out for the changes to take effect